# Delete rows with smallest int SQL mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in sql and I have some problems with complex selection. How can I delete two rows with smallest *base_amount* with *base_currency* 'USD'?

[image: Transaction table]

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in a `DELETE`:

```
delete from t
    where base_currency = 'USD'
    order by base_amount asc
    limit 2;
```